# Confusion with Dependency Injection and Provider Hierarchy in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have a setup where I'm injecting a service into another service, and I've provided different values for the same token at different levels of the injector hierarchy. However, the injected value doesn't match my expectations. Here are the details of my setup:

1. I have a service **MyService** which I've provided in **AppModule** and which I'm injecting into **AppComponent**.
2. I've provided the token '**innerDependency**' with the value '*root*' in the **AppModule's** providers.
3. Additionally, I've provided the same '**innerDependency**' token with the value '*local*' in **AppComponent's** providers.
4. I'm injecting '**innerDependency**' into the constructor of **MyService**.
5. Despite having provided '*local*' at the **AppComponent** level, when I log the value of '**innerDependency**' in **MyService's** constructor, I'm seeing '*root*' instead of '*local*'.

I thought that the active injector should be **AppComponent's ElementInjector** and all searches should start from there. But it seems that once angular uses the **ModuleInjector** of **AppModule** for injecting **MyService**, it stays there and any new searches will start from there.
What am I misunderstanding about Angular injector hierarchy and dependency injection?

**Code Snippets:**

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MyService } from './my.service';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [MyService, {provide: 'innerDependency', useValue: 'root'}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './my.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [{provide: 'innerDependency', useValue: 'local'}]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(service : MyService){}
}
```

my.service.ts

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    constructor(@Inject('innerDependency') innerDep: String){
        console.log(innerDep);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add object to your Injectable annotation with attribute

```
{providedIn: 'root'}
```

The service should look like that:

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
@Injectable(
  {providedIn: 'root'}
)
export class MyService {
    constructor(@Inject('innerDependency') innerDep: String){
        console.log(innerDep);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already provided MyService in AppModule using the providers array. What difference would this make ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you completed your step 2.

> 2. I've provided the token 'innerDependency' with the value 'root' in the AppModule's providers.

I may be misunderstanding if that has been something you have already tried, but it appears as though you still need to add it to your modules. It is in your app.component.ts.

To get it to work how you want, you may need to specify the `innerDependency` at the module level for your myService:

app.module.ts:

```
providers: [
    MyService,
    { provide: 'innerDependency', useValue: 'local' } 
  ],
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In angular you have tree of injectors in DI. For your case there are 2 injectors, lets call them Root and AppComponentInjector. And Root injector is parent for AppComopnentInjector.

So in Root injector you have 2 providers:

- `innerDependency` (value: 'root')
- `MyService`

In AppComponentInjector:

- `innerDependency` (value: 'local')

After that when you import `MyService` in AppComponent, DI tries to find instance/provider for `MyService` and do no find it in AppComponentInjector. After that it tries to find provider for `MyService` in parent (Root) injector. In Root injector DI finds provider and try to create an instance (Root injector responsible for creation of the instance because `MyService` provider declared there). When Root injector creates instance of `MyService` it looking for provider for `innerDependency` and finds provider with `root` value. If you want to have `local` value in your service instance you can add provider for `MyService` in AppComponentInjector, then instance for this provider will be created within AppComponentInjector and `local` value will be found/used.